# How to access service in another feature module?

Tags: javascript, angular, typescript

I am using Angular 2/4. I have feature modules that includes everything that corresponds to that Feature. So for example I have a Building Module and a Client Module.

[image: Example of folder structure for Building Module]

This is essentially the same structure for my Client Feature Module.

Now in my Building module I need to access the ClientService as I need a list of the Clients as they are associated with Building. Can I just Import the Client Service like this?

```
     import { BuildingService } from "../buildingservice";
     import { ClientService } from "../../client/clientservice";

    @Component({
      selector: 'building-detail',
      templateUrl: './building-detail.component.html',
      providers: [BuildingService, ClientService]
    })

     export class BuildingDetailComponent extends ComponentBase {

      constructor(private buildingService: BuildingService, private clientService: ClientService) {
    super();
}
  }
```

Would it be better if I put my ClientService in a SharedServices folder or would this be OK?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

for a service to work, it should just be added to the providers array of any module of your choice as it really depends on how you want to structure your project as this will have no effect on functionality.

the service will work in any component you inject to it the service whether it was registered in the building module or the client module.

Answer (score 1):

How you organize your code is totally up to you. There's nothing wrong with importing modules through an intricate path.

If some code is shared between very distant modules, it might make sense to reflect that in how the code is organized. Such a renaming something to "shared" and placing it in a higher directory. But again, you decide :)